# Defining _write property of stream.Writable the right way to write as many times

Tags: node.js

lets say i have an object

logfile is an actual file.

```
wStream = require("stream").Writable
```

and i defined:

```
logStream = function logStream () {
                    this.file = logfile;
                    wStream.call(this);
                };

    require("util").inherits(logStream, wStream);
    logStream.prototype._write = function logStream_write (data, enc, cb) {
        fs.appendFile(this.file, data, 'utf-8', function WatchLogErr(err) {
           if (err) {throw Error(err);}
        });};

const log = new logStream();

log.on('finish', function () {
        console.log("finished writing to log stream");
    });
```

If I write

```
log.write("watching changes\n");
log.write("watching changes\n");
```

It writes only once and then doesn't write.

Why? Is it ending prematurely?
How can I make it write without ending?

**UPDATE**

if, say i pass a cb to a function, fn (args, cb) {//do something; cb(x);};
then I can define while firing fn: fn([1,2,3], shifoo (x) { console.log(x);});
correct?

So where I am gona use this cb?
Say

```
log.write("watching changes2\n", 'utf-8', function (data) {
        console.log("wrote " + data.toString());
    });
```

doing that gives me this error:

```
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at Error (native)
    at logStream.emit (events.js:87:13)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:317:10)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:335:5)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:105:5)
```

Comment: Are you missing another `});` before your `const log = new logStream();`? Otherwise it looks like you're instantiating a `logStream` inside your `_write()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `cb()` inside of your `appendFile()` callback. This is needed to signal that you are done with the `data` and a next chunk can be passed to `_write()`. For example:

```
logStream.prototype._write = function logStream_write (data, enc, cb) {
  fs.appendFile(this.file, data, 'utf-8', cb);
});
```

Comment: how can i use this cb from outside? can u give me an eg?

Comment: Well, if you really need to do that, you could store the callback on the instance somewhere, like `this._writeCb = cb;`. However be sure to to clear that property (e.g. set to `null`) once you've called the callback to avoid any potential problems.

Comment: if, say i pass a cb to a function, fn (args, cb) {//do something; cb(x);};
then I can define while firing fn: fn([1,2,3], shifoo (x) { console.log(x);});
correct?

So where I am gona use this cb?
Say 
log.write("watching changes2\n", 'utf-8', function (data) {
        console.log("wrote " + data.toString());
    });

Comment: can u pls give me an eg on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361030/defining-write-property-of-stream-writable-the-right-way-to-write-as-many-times/32361502?noredirect=1#comment52596085_32361502 

I am having trouble searching for a sound and crisp code eg over net;